# My mouse cursor is not moving

Tags: windows, mouse, cursor, sensors

So today whilst i was doing something on the laptop my mouse started to act weird. The cursor wouldnt stopped at random times for like 2 seconds.
But now my cursor doesnt even move! I checked the back of my mouse, looks like the sensor wont even detect the surface, whether i used my mousepad or not.
This is a brand new mouse. I just got it 2 days ago.
Also, this is a school laptop so i cant do much.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshoot, try using another mouse. If that fixes it, then the other mouse has a hardware issue. Most likely just a bad mouse if it's only two days old.

You could also see if you turn off the trackpad (laptop mouse pad) with one of the hotkeys (normally one of the F keys).